# Simulate <script> tags with Webpack

Tags: javascript, plugins, webpack, strophe

I'm trying to import two libraries globally into a project. What I'm trying to achieve can be done as follows (note the `<script>` tags in the `<head>`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="node_modules/strophe/strophe.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/strophejs-plugins/disco/strophe.disco.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Strophe.js and the disco plugin work in much the same way as jQuery and it's plugins, by creating a global `Strophe` object which the disco plugin then extends with additional methods. On it's own the disco plugin is useless and, in this case, the `Strophe` object without the disco plugin is also useless.

I'd like to remove the need to add these script tags to my html and I think I can use webpack to do so. I'm working on an existing codebase, so I don't want to have to add imports/requires at the top of each file that utilizes these files.

I can make Strophe globally available with the `ProvidePlugin` as follows:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Strophe: 'strophe'
})
```

Unfortunately, this is no use to me without the disco plugin.

I'm aware that I could use something like the imports-loader to explicitly import the disco plugin and evaluate it in the correct context, however this would require me to add imports to all files that use it, which I'd like to avoid.

Is it possible to use Webpack to make the Strophe variable (which has been extended with the disco plugin) globally available to all files without importing it in each?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) option, provided by webpack. And, of course, you have to maintain the ProvidePlugin

Comment: I've been looking at the externals option, and in fact I am using it to make strophe globally available. I'm just struggling with how to have the plugin modify that global object. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure how Strophe works under the hoods when it's imported by pointing straight to its node_modules directory. You could also use a the [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader)

If it was me, I would tell to webpack to create a different vendor bundle only for your Strophe. You can use CommonsChunkPlugin, you will name your bundle `strophe.bundle.js`. Obviously you will import this bundle before your main bundle